# git clone - detached HEAD - Get tag name that was cloned from

Tags: git

This question is about getting the tag name that was cloned from to get into a detached HEAD state, not how to recover from a detached HEAD state.

We have a build system that clones various git repos by tags which are used as versions. Each repo builds an output file that is versioned by the tag name. This works well enough, but a problem arrises when there are two tags on the same commit. The git commands that are being used do not handle this situation.

For example, I have a repo like this with two version tags on the same commit.

```
git init
touch .gitignore
git add .
git commit -am "Initial commit"
git tag release-v1
git tag release-v2
```

If I wanted to build this repo with version "release-v2", our build system would check out this repo like this:

`git clone --single-branch --depth 1 -b release-v2 repo.git`

From a Makefile inside the repo we are using this command to get the version from the tag name:

`VERSION := $(shell git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)`

This command seems to always point to the first "release-v1" tag though and not necessarily the tag that was cloned from.

I found this command which does return both tags, but it still doesn't tell me which tag was cloned.

```
$ git tag --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD)
release-v1
release-v2
```

Is there an alternative command that would always return the tag that the repo was cloned from or does git not even know that because the tag just points to the commit ID?

This build system is very custom and definitely has some issues, so I am open to alternative checkout methods altogether if it doesn't require too many large changes.

Comment: A regular tag is a one-way mapping: given a tag, you can get a commit, but a commit doesn't know what tags might refer to it. If you use annotated tags, then the tag itself *is* a specific commit.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But if I checkout from a tag instead of cloning from a tag, git seems to know what tag it was detached from.
`git checkout release-v2`. Then `git branch` returns `* (detached from release-v2)`. I can't figure out how it knows that though.

Comment: Hm. Possibly the ref log? (Which would know what `HEAD` was previously a reference to.)

Comment: What do you mean *how it knows*? You put it into your command line.

Comment: I know I put it in the command line, but it's clearly persisting it somewhere. The HEAD is the same and both tags still point to HEAD, but git knows that it was detached from release-v2 as opposed to release-v1.

Comment: Because *you* put this in the command line. You mean that it knows about tag after the operation had been done? Yes, it keeps it.

Comment: `git checkout` writes the information to the HEAD reflog; `git status` fishes it out. This is not a 100% reliable process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Simply change the command your build system runs from:

```
git clone --single-branch --depth 1 -b release-v2 repo.git
```

to

```
git clone --single-branch --depth 1 -b release-v2 --no-tags repo.git
```

The `--no-tags` option has been available since git version 2.14.0:

```
--no-tags
    Don’t clone any tags, and set remote.<remote>.tagOpt=--no-tags in the config, ensuring that future git pull and git fetch
    operations won’t follow any tags. Subsequent explicit tag fetches will still work, (see git-fetch(1)).

    Can be used in conjunction with --single-branch to clone and maintain a branch with no references other than a single
    cloned branch. This is useful e.g. to maintain minimal clones of the default branch of some repository for search
    indexing.
```

---

Also verified with git 2.14.0, and it works as you'd expect:

```
π shang@raspberrypi:/tmp/git $ git version
git version 2.14.0
π shang@raspberrypi:/tmp/git $ 
π shang@raspberrypi:/tmp/git $ git clone --single-branch --depth 1 -b release-v2 --no-tags https://github.com/sding3/stackoverflow60400330.git             
Cloning into 'stackoverflow60400330'...
<...snipped...>

π shang@raspberrypi:/tmp/git/stackoverflow60400330 $  git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
release-v2
π shang@raspberrypi:/tmp/git/stackoverflow60400330 $ git tag --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD)
release-v2
```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I wanted and requires very minimal changes. Thank you!